# Practicing inserting data into an array by using binary search, few problems

Tags: java, arrays, insert, binary-search

I'm trying to create a method which inserts and then sort elements in form of binary form.

The problem I am experiencing that my code doesn't insert data correctly which means that output does not appear to be in order at all.

The list is not organized, and data is added in order that is being inserted.

Now, 2 questions, what am I doing wrong here? And how to fix this?

```
public void insertBinarySearch(long value) // put element into array
{       
    int j = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    int upper = elems-1;
    int cur = 0;

    while (cur < elems)
    {
        cur = (lower + upper ) / 2;

        if(a[cur] < value)
        {
            j = cur + 1;
            break;
        }
        else if(a[cur] > value)
        {
            j = cur;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if(a[cur] < value)
                lower = cur + 1;
            else
                upper = cur - 1;
        }
    }

    for(int k = elems; k > j; k--)
        a[k] = a[k-1];

    a[j] = value;

    elems++;
}
```

Comment: If you're adding a lot of elements and then traversing it'd be better to just add the items and sort later as needed. This looks like it involves a lot of shifting.

Comment: I would not agree on this. Since we can do organize elements first, then we don't need to create additional loop which would add more computation time to this method (what if that loop had millions of elements). As I was explained in class, doing this way I am doing would save time and processing consumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (lower <= upper)
{
    curIn = (lower + upper ) / 2;

        if(a[curIn] < value)
            lower = cur + 1;
        else if(a[curIn] > value)
            upper = cur - 1;
        else if (a[curIn] == value)
            break;
}
if(a[curIn] <= value)
    j = curIn + 1;
else j = curIn;
```

should work.

Comment: This work very well except one thing. It inserts extra 0 value to the begging of array.

Comment: This simply finds the position to insert it. How does it insert the extra zero?

Comment: I'm not sure, really. I will figure this out though. Thanks again for help!

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, just by checking if number of elements is not 0 will not enter 0 value as fist value to the array. :)

Answer (score 1):

Dude, you almost got it, just debug the code and find some missing statement (if's). If you find those missing statements, you code looks better than mine. Don't look mine, you are there, very close.

Let me know for any mistakes and discrepancies etc. Happy coding!!

```
public class Insertion {
    private int[] a;
    int n;
    int c;

    public Insertion()
    {
        a = new int[10];
        n=0;
    }

    int find(int key)
    {
        int lowerbound = 0;
        int upperbound = n-1;

        while(true)
        {
            c = (lowerbound + upperbound)/2;
            if(n==0)
                return 0;
            if(lowerbound>=upperbound)
            {
                if(a[c]<key)
                    return c++;
                else
                    return c;
            }
            if(a[c]>key && a[c-1]<key)
                return c;
            else if (a[c]<key && a[c+1]>key)
                return c++;
            else
            {
                if(a[c]>key)
                    upperbound = c-1;
                else
                    lowerbound = c+1;
            }
        }
    }

    void insert(int key)
    {
       find(key);
       for(int k=n;k>c;k--)
       {
           a[k]=a[k-1];
       }
       a[c]=key;
       n++;
    }
    void display()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Insertion i=new Insertion();
        i.insert(56);
        i.insert(1);
        i.insert(78);
        i.insert(3);
        i.insert(4);
        i.insert(200);
        i.insert(6);
        i.insert(7);
        i.insert(1000);
        i.insert(9);
        i.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to insert an item into an unsorted list, you can't expect the list to be sorted if you don't directly sort it afterwards.

Binary search can only be used on a sorted list.  Your results mean nothing otherwise: after all, if you're searching for an element - let's use 8 for example - how do you know if an item belongs before or after 8?

```
[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ]
```

Notice that, if I find 8, I know that everything after it is greater than 8, and everything before is less than 8.  But what about this list?

```
[ 1 4 11 9 8 6 7 2 5 3 10 ]
```

Yikes! Now, looking at 8, you can see that the position of 8 no longer has anything to do with the items that are less than or greater than 8.  Trying to find an element with binary search in this list will give you incorrect information, whether it finds the item you're looking for or not.

To get this working, make sure the list is always sorted (which should be the case if you *always* insert items into the correct position in the list), or to sort it before inserting new elements.  Binary search will serve you just fine then.

Comment: I am searching for a location where number is higher than previous number and lower than next number then by using this place I am moving the array entries that are after the field by one which will give me empty space where I can insert my value. The point of this code is to insert the items after indexing items.

Comment: So the list _is_ sorted before this method is called? I was running with the assumption it wasn't, since you said 'The list is not organized'.  Sorry for the confusion.